# Authenticate as administrator?

Tags: .net, vb.net, uac, windows-authentication

I'm developing an installer, and I would like to write to a folder accessible only to administrators. So, I need to display the UAC dialog and authenticate as an administrator. I know I could do this by having a separate executable that I run from the installer GUI, but I'd rather a solution that allows me to authenticate whenever I want in the application. Is this possible in .NET?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can not change privilege level mid process, once a process has started it is stuck at that privilege level. You must launch a separate process with elevated privileges and communicate with it with IPC to update the GUI.

If you are writing a installer the best thing is to just mark the installers own application manifest as administrative rights itself so it will request admin privileges when it starts as you will need it every time anyway.

Comment: The reason I don't want to do that (e.g. request administrator rights immediately) is because I want to be able to install to local/appdata folders as well.

Comment: Then you will need to spawn a second process with no GUI and use some form of [IPC](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365574%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) ([WCF](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms735119%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) using pipes would be the likely candidate but you will have to play with permissions as the default ones will not work when you have a high priv. process talking to a low priv. process) to tell it what to do.

Answer (score 0):

You must run a new process with this configuration for the `Manifest` file :

```
<security>
  <requestedPrivileges>
    <requestedExecutionLevel level="requireAdministrator" />
  </requestedPrivileges>
</security>
```

Answer (score 0):

As an alternative to starting a new process elevated, you can create a new COM object elevated.

---

Some installers use an approach similar to what you're trying to do. An example to this would be [foobar2000 installer](http://www.foobar2000.org/). At the first screen it asks where it would a standard *(all users)* or portable setup. If standard is selected, it prompts for elevation and relaunches itself.

So your simplest bet would be to collect data from user, then relaunch itself or another executable as Administrator to do the actual job passing it parameters with user's selections.